# Multiple GNOME sessions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, nfs, vnc

I'm working in a corporate network environment and am having trouble with multiple GNOME sessions. My desktop runs Ubuntu 10.10 and I would like to start another GNOME session on a remote machine running RHEL4 through VNC. My home directory is shared over NFS so the two sessions are always interfering with each other. An extra complication is that both machines are running different versions of GNOME. Is this possible? Would changing the last line from my xstartup.startx file from exec /etx/C11/xinit/xinitrc to gnome-session --choose-session=VNC work?

Comment: You can try asking this question on [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), which has a few Gnome power-users. Another possible site [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), as people running different versions of Ubuntu alongside each other would run into a similar problem. If you do post the question on another site, please link the questions to each other, so people can easily find answers that were left on another site.